# glfwSwapInterval() causing flickering/broken drawing

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw

I'm currently working on a small 2D platformer project using OpenGL, trying to do most things from scratch as a learning exercise.

The problem I'm having at the moment seems to be related to using glfwSwapInterval(n);. When I set the swap interval to 0 (i.e., no vsync), a GameObject I'm rendering renders perfectly fine, and moves around smoothly. Setting it to 1 causes the object to either not be rendered, or to flicker and the corners jump around. Setting it to higher values worsens the problem.

The code I believe is relevant is below.

game.cpp (main game class):

```
void Game::runGame()
{
    // Some init things here but not important
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(_disp.getWindow()))
    {
        // delta is set up here
        glfwPollEvents();
        for (auto& obj : _gobs) { obj->update(delta) };
        _disp.checkInput(_cont.getKeys()); // Only checks for Esc press to close window
        _disp.render(_gobs);
    }
    _disp.close();
}
```

display.cpp (handles window creation):

```
bool Display::initGL()
{
    // Majority of window creation code is above here, but generic and probably irrelevant
    glViewport(0, 0, _scrWidth, _scrHeight);
    glfwSwapInterval(0); // Seems to cause flickering with nonzero values
    glfwSetInputMode(_window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    return true;
}

void Display::render(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>> gobs)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    for (auto& obj : gobs) { obj->render(); }
    glfwSwapBuffers(_window);
}
```

gameobject.cpp (object class):

```
void GameObject::render()
{
    if (_vaoid)
    {
        _shader.use();
        glBindVertexArray(_vaoid);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas on what could be causing this? It feels like I must have missed out a window hint or something similar but I couldn't find any documentation that mentions that.

Edit: Shader code causing the problem:
basicvert.vs:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position.xy = position;
    gl_Position.z = 0.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the cause of the problem, eventually.

As it turns out, it wasn't caused by glfwSwapInterval() - however, setting it to 0 simply seems to mask the problem due to the much higher framerate.

In my vertex shader, I was passing in the position as a vec2, and setting gl_Position as follows:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position.xy = position;
    gl_Position.z = 0.0f;
    // gl_Position.w does not get set -> left as an undefined value?
}
```

As a result, the w component of gl_Position was not being set. Setting this to 1.0f resolved the problem:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Works
}
```